Large smallest square in a sum of three squares?
It's well-known that all positive integers $n$ not of the form $4^a(8b+7)$ can be written as the sum of three squares. Recently I wrote a computer program to exhibit the actual squares $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ and noticed that
$$f(n) = \min_{\substack{x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}\\x^2+y^2+z^2 = n}} |x|$$
is quite small---it seemingly scales more like $\operatorname{polylog}(n)$ rather than $\sqrt{n}$. Are any upper bounds known on the smallest square in a sum of three squares? Alternatively, are there known families of $n$ for which $f(n)$ is large? Or values of $p$ for which $f(3p^2) = p$?

EDIT: Following @will-jagy's advice, here is a table of values of $n$ for which $f(n)$ is larger than $f(m)$ for all $m<n$, for $n$ up to $10^9$ (and ignoring all multiples of four, since $f(4n) = 2f(n)$):
n: f(n)
3: 1
22: 2
43: 3
133: 4
142: 5
427: 9
1842: 11
2347: 13
5173: 15
7507: 17
14953: 18
18043: 21
41899: 25
61147: 27
93235: 33
160147: 35
315403: 39
566899: 45
754387: 49
1523467: 51
1574227: 55
1839091: 61
2483947: 63
5687803: 91
55933123: 105
87194083: 111
583969387: 117

Interestingly, these $n$ all have very few ($\leq 3$) prime factors.

EDIT 2: Here are some plots, where I used Mathematica to fit a model of the form $a \log^{5/2} n$, $a \log^{3/2}n$, and $a n^b$ to the above data:


@WillJagy:  I get a 404 error for the first link.

$ \limsup f(n) = \infty,$   using Chinese Remainder theorem. Let $n \equiv 3 \pmod 8,$  then $n-1 \equiv 3 \pmod 9,$  then $n - 4 \equiv 7 \pmod {49}, $  so on up to $n -u^2 \equiv W \pmod{W^2}$ for large prime $W \equiv 3 \pmod 4$

$f(n)$ is the smallest number $x$ such that $n-x^2$ is the sum of two squares. Sums of two squares are reasonably common, more common than primes for instance: the probability that a number near $n$ can be written as the sum of two squares is asymptotic to a constant times $1/\sqrt{\log n}$. Thus the probabilistic heuristic is that the expected size of $f(n)$ has order of magnitude $\sqrt{\log n}$, and a further heuristic using the Borel–Cantelli lemma suggests that the largest $f(n)$ can ever get is a constant times $(\log n)^{3/2}$.

As a heuristic this makes sense, though of course the sums of two squares aren't uniformly distributed, and this leads to anomalies that contradict the heuristic such as that $n-x^2$ is never the sum of two squares when $n = 4^a(8b+7)$, and that $f(3\cdot 2^{2k}) = 2^k \neq O(k^{3/2})$.

Excellent points @user7530, a refined heuristic should definitely take these points into account. I guess the heuristic as given would work for $n\equiv1,2,3,5,6\pmod8$.

Is there any reason to expect $\log^{5/2} n$ rather than $\log^{3/2} n$? The fit for the former is better than for the latter (on the admittedly very sparse set of data I generated); see plots above.
